# What's the most concise way to read query parameters in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'd like to read the values of URL query parameters using AngularJS.  I'm accessing the HTML with the following URL:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/test.html?target=bob`

As expected, `location.search` is `"?target=bob"`.
For accessing the value of *target*, I've found various examples listed on the web, but none of them work in AngularJS 1.0.0rc10.  In particular, the following are all `undefined`:

- `$location.search.target`
- `$location.search['target']`
- `$location.search()['target']`

Anyone know what will work? (I'm using `$location` as a parameter to my controller)

---

Update:

I've posted a solution below, but I'm not entirely satisfied with it.
The documentation at [Developer Guide: Angular Services: Using $location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/%24location) states the following about `$location`:

> When should I use $location?
>
> Any time your application needs to react to a change in the current
>   URL or if you want to change the current URL in the browser.

For my scenario, my page will be opened from an external webpage with a query parameter, so I'm not "reacting to a change in the current URL" per se.  So maybe `$location` isn't the right tool for the job (for the ugly details, see my answer below). I've therefore changed the title of this question from "How to read query parameters in AngularJS using $location?" to "What's the most concise way to read query parameters in AngularJS?".  Obviously I could just use javascript and regular expression to parse `location.search`, but going that low-level for something so basic really offends my programmer sensibilities.

So: is there a better way to use `$location` than I do in my answer, or is there a concise alternate?

Comment: Shouldn't $location.search()['target'] work?

Comment: This does not work, because there is no hash after the path. `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test.html#?target=bob` would work, notice the `#` before the `?`. `$location` is a second level routing method which does not get sent to the server.

Comment: @DanielF @rob, you're both right. `$location.search()['target']` works after `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` has been called in a modern browser.

Answer (score 201):

You can inject [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) (requires [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)) into your controller. Here's an example from the docs:

```
// Given:
// URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
// Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
//
// Then
$routeParams ==> {chapterId:1, sectionId:2, search:'moby'}
```

EDIT: You can also get and set query parameters with the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service (available in `ng`), particularly its `search` method: [$location.search()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#searchh).

$routeParams are less useful after the controller's initial load; `$location.search()` can be called anytime.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and link!  I read the page and also attempted to set up a working sample.  However, the approach won't work out for me, because I really don't want to use routing in this case.  This was a helpful suggestion nonetheless, and I'll upvote it once I have enough stackoverflow rep.

Comment: I would say @pkozlowski.opensource 's answer is more accurate in this situation

Comment: Not quite .. query paramaters are included in the $routeParams object with the normal route parameters. and you can read them/set them with $location.search().  I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Jakub is right. They are different things. When you use the "search" in angular, it appends the query to the hash (end of the URL). The RFC spec for URI states that the query params should prepend (not append) the hash. Thus the "search" is a construct that only angular will extrapolate and interpret. This is why only HTML5 mode will work for the solution above, because you are delegating all requests to one page (at the server level) regardless of the actual URI.

Comment: this only works if you want to use route in angularJS !

Comment: If this isn't working for you, check which router in Angular you are using. In my case I am using `$stateProvider` which means I would use `$stateParams` in my controller to get the URL params

Answer (score 193):

Good that you've managed to get it working with the html5 mode but it is also possible to make it work in the hashbang mode.

You could simply use:

```
$location.search().target
```

to get access to the 'target' search param.

For the reference, here is the working jsFiddle: http://web.archive.org/web/20130317065234/http://jsfiddle.net/PHnLb/7/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $location) {

    $scope.location = $location;
    $scope.$watch('location.search()', function() {
        $scope.target = ($location.search()).target;
    }, true);

    $scope.changeTarget = function(name) {
        $location.search('target', name);
    }
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <a href="#!/test/?target=Bob">Bob</a>
    <a href="#!/test/?target=Paul">Paul</a>
    
    <hr/>    
    URL 'target' param getter: {{target}}<br>
    Full url: {{location.absUrl()}}
    <hr/>
    
    <button ng-click="changeTarget('Pawel')">target=Pawel</button>
    
</div>
```

Comment: do you need the parentheses around $location.search() ?

Comment: @Magne: yes, you need parentheses, $location.search is a method https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: Don't forget that if you do not use `HTML5Mode(true)` then only params after #/ are available or get added to url with #/ at the beginning.

Comment: @nandin: No, you do **not** need the parentheses *around* `$location.search()`. I'm not sure why this answer puts them there.

Comment: @nandin, that is a strange argument

Comment: @nandin Parentheses shouldn't be required. The method call return an object and the dot syntax interrogates that object. Akin to a fluent interface.

Comment: I feel like @nandin misunderstood the "Do you need parentheses" question. You *do* need the parentheses after search, but not the ones around the entirety of `$location.search()`.

Comment: @K.Carpenter I agree. I edited the answer to fix the syntax. (I know it's an old one, but it's a good reference)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, given the large number of upvotes, I figured many people valued this question/answer.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource Currently the JSFiddle link doesn't work. Do you by any chance still have the source code?

Comment: @UliKöhler you can use ellis-whitehead's code below, should be the same

Comment: A little off topic, but I'm really pleased to see an archive.org link for the jsfiddle

Answer (score 57):

To give a partial answer my own question, here is a working sample for HTML5 browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0rc10/angular-1.0.0rc10.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', [], function($locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
    function QueryCntl($scope, $location) {
      $scope.target = $location.search()['target'];
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="QueryCntl">

Target: {{target}}<br/>

</body>
</html>
```

The key was to call `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` as done above.  It now works when opening `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test.html?target=bob`. I'm not happy about the fact that it won't work in older browsers, but I might use this approach anyway.

An alternative that would work with older browsers would be to drop the `html5mode(true)` call and use the following address with hash+slash instead:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/test.html#/?target=bob`

The relevant documentation is at [Developer Guide: Angular Services: Using $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) (strange that my google search didn't find this...).

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been pulling my hair out trying to read in the query params. Kept getting 'undefined' as you mentioned above. Setting mode to html5 worked.

Comment: Shouldn't the `ng-controller` attribute of `<body>` be set to `MyApp`?

Comment: Looks like starting with Angular 1.3, in order to use html5Mode you also need to either add a `<base href="/" />` tag, or add `requireBase: false` as another parameter to the call to html5Mode. [Details here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase)

Answer (score 19):

It can be done by two ways:

1. Using `$routeParams`

Best and recommended solution is to use `$routeParams` into your controller. 
It Requires the `ngRoute` module to be installed.

```
   function MyController($scope, $routeParams) {
      // URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
      // Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
      // $routeParams ==> {chapterId:'1', sectionId:'2', search:'moby'}
      var search = $routeParams.search;
  }
```

2. Using `$location.search()`.

There is a caveat here. It will work only with HTML5 mode. By default, it does not work for the URL which does not have hash(`#`) in it `http://localhost/test?param1=abc&param2=def`

You can make it work by adding `#/` in the URL. `http://localhost/test#/?param1=abc&param2=def`

`$location.search()` to return an object like:

```
{
  param1: 'abc',
  param2: 'def'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice with #/

Answer (score 10):

$location.search() will work only with HTML5 mode turned on and only on supporting browser.

This will work always:

$window.location.search

Answer (score 6):

Just to summerize .

If your app is being loaded from external links then angular wont detect this as a URL change so $loaction.search() would give you an empty object . To solve this you need to set following in your app config(app.js)

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider,     $locationProvider) 
{
   $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
         controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/'
      });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 }]);
```

Comment: Yep. This was a pain to find. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just a precision to Ellis Whitehead's answer. `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` won't work with new version of angularjs without specifying the base URL for the application with a `<base href="">` tag or setting the parameter `requireBase` to `false`

[From the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase) :

> If you configure $location to use html5Mode (history.pushState), you need to specify the base URL for the application with a  tag or configure $locationProvider to not require a base tag by passing a definition object with requireBase:false to $locationProvider.html5Mode():

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use $location.$$search.yourparameter

Comment: The `$$search` is an internal variable, the use of which is not such a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I found that for an SPA HTML5Mode causes lots of 404 error problems, and it is not necessary to make $location.search work in this case.  In my case I want to capture a URL query string parameter when a user comes to my site, regardless of which "page" they initially link to, AND be able to send them to that page once they log in.  So I just capture all that stuff in app.run

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (fromState.name === "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        $rootScope.initialPage = toState.name;
        $rootScope.initialParams = toParams;
        return;
    }
    if ($location.search().hasOwnProperty('role')) {
        $rootScope.roleParameter = $location.search()['role'];
    }
    ...
}
```

then later after login I can say 
    $state.go($rootScope.initialPage, $rootScope.initialParams)

Answer (score -3):

It's a bit late, but I think your problem was your URL. If instead of

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/test.html?target=bob
```

you had

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/test.html#/?target=bob
```

I'm pretty sure it would have worked. Angular is really picky about its #/

Comment: That is only if you are not enabling HTML5 mode. The #/ is not always there in Angular urls.

Comment: It is if you are building an SPA.  All of my urls have a #.  And HTML5Mode means 1) 404 on page refresh and 2) direct urls won't work.  Seems like a high price to pay.