# Best way to parse a query string with AngularJS without using html5mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What's the best way to parse a query string in Angular **without** using **html5mode**? (*Not using html5mode because we need to support older browsers*)

I get the same undefined results whether or not I use a hash:

```
http://localhost/test?param1=abc&param2=def
http://localhost/test#/param1=abc&param2=def
```

$routeParams and $location.search() both return undefined:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ["ngRoute"]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ["$scope", "$routeParams", "$location",
  function($scope, $routeParams, $location) {

  console.log($routeParams, $routeParams.abc); //undefined, undefined
  console.log($location.search(), $location.search().abc); //undefined, undefined

}]);
```

I can parse the window.location.search myself, but I'm hoping there is a better way to do it in Angular.

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/alBGFAkfqncVyK7iv8Ia?p=preview

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063673/whats-the-most-concise-way-to-read-query-parameters-in-angularjs) and haven't found a solution. I must be missing something. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So the problem with your plunker will probably be because of it being inside of an iframe. Is the same issue happening locally?

Comment: Yes, same results locally. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

the query params should go after the hash:

`http://localhost/test#/?param1=abc&param2=def`

this should allow `$location.search()` to return an object like:

```
{
  param1: 'abc',
  param2: 'def'
}
```

Comment: Agh - I didn't realize you needed both the # and the ?. That makes total sense - thank you!

Comment: Or simply you can use `$routeParams`.