# Angularjs - "Arrays" in the url and ngModel

Tags: angularjs, forms, query-string

I'm having some troubles with arrays in the ngModel.

Imagine I have a movie databse and I want to search a movie where appears some actors:

```
$scope.search = {
    actors: [1, 2, 3] // actors' ID
};
```

I'm using $location.search. In order to send an array, I have to "parse" the model and send this:

```
{ 'actors[]': [1, 2, 3] };
```

So the url will be: **search?actor%5B%5D=1&actor%5B%5D=2&actor%5B%5D=3** (I'm using PHP as backend).

The problem is when I refresh the page with that URL, I'd like to have that inputs loaded, and I have to do the "reverse", so that "actors[]" have to be "actors" because the ngModel key is "actors".

I feel that I'm overcomplicated too much and there is a better way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thx!

edit:

**Plunkr** (Url wrong and parsed generated)

http://plnkr.co/edit/aYawMwqRrCjN9ZBxB6Us?p=preview

Comment: you dont need []. { 'actors': [1, 2, 3] } will do

Comment: @PitchaiPazhani using $location.search the url is not generating correctly

Comment: So you want to create an array of actors (that you want to use as search criteria in your back end movie DB) and then get the response back with an array (containing movies featuring those actors) and then display it in your view (as a result of a give search)?

Comment: @ChrisHermut Yes but the result and the queries are not the problem. The problem is that I have to "parse" the data when I send to the server (actors to actors[]) and the reverse when I'm load the form with the query string and the actors ngModel input (ui-select or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to parse your query string as discussed in [Best way to parse a query string with AngularJS without using html5mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692369/best-way-to-parse-a-query-string-with-angularjs-without-using-html5mode).

And then you can just repopulate your $scope.actors array with data coming from that parse.

Comment: So you want to read that query string as (simplified) actors[0]=1&actors[1]=2 etc.?

Comment: Yes but ui-select won't load the selected items because de ngModel key is "actors", not "actors[]", but occurs just the opposite when submitting the form, "actors[]" has to be send in order to generate the url correctly.