# Pulled out all my hair on an Angular unpr error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

So I am getting an angular [$injector:unpr] error.  Yes, I know what that normally means...I haven't defined something somewhere, or I am redefining the module over and over, or the like...but for the life of me I'm struggling to see the issue in my code.

I'm sure I'm missing something insanely basic, but after I've stared at code for a couple of hours, I go blind to it.

My HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="email">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Authentication</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller="EmailAuthController as auth">
        <h1>Authentication</h1>
        <p>Request: [{{auth.request}}]</p>
        <p>{{auth.response}}</p>
        <p>{{1+2}}</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/email.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My `email.js` file (As you can see, I've commented out some stuff to try to isolate the issue):

```
/* global angular parseGet */
function parseGet(val) {
    var result = '', // = "Not found",
        tmp = [];
    var items = location.search.substr(1).split('&');
    for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
        tmp = items[index].split('=');
        if (tmp[0] === val) {
            result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

(function () {
    angular
        .module('email', [])
        .controller('EmailAuthController', [ '$scope','authFactory', function ($scope,authFactory) {
            var vm = this,
                req = parseGet('hash') || '';
            vm.request = req;
            // authFactory.validate(req)
            //     .then(function (response) {
            //         vm.response = response.data;
            //     });
        }])
        .factory('authFactory', [ '$rootScope', '$http', 'config', function ($rootScope, $http, config) {
            var validate = function (hash) {
                var url = config.SERVICE_URI + '/auth/email/' + hash;

                return $http.get(url);
            };

            return {
                validate: validate
            };
        }]);


})();
```

Comment: can you post the full error from the console?

Comment: what is `config` provider? `unpr` is `unknown provider` angular doesn't know what is `config`, you have not declare it.

Comment: You can just click to link in your console.error, and go deeper and deeper by links to get actual error.

Comment: Does moving your scripts to the bottom of the page make any difference? Also, parseGet should probably be encapsulated as a service. And where is config defined? And as the others have said, where is the full error?

Comment: About `parseGet`: take a look to [$location.search()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20693015/2110496) or `$routeParams`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you've given it appears `config` is not defined in your `authFactory` injection.

`.factory('authFactory', [ '$rootScope', '$http', 'config', function(a, b, c) {} ]); // config is not defined`

Comment: @BrianS Hate it when that happens :p

Comment: DANGINT!

I was all prepared to dismiss out of hand this answer as I *do* have that file, just commented out...wait... commented out!  So uncomment it... nothing... SEE, I **knew** it was the wrong answer!

Wait... that config is set up as a factory for a separate module... so it would never work anyway! &!%@*^&!*

Thank you, you slapped some sense into me :)