# Reading query string data from requested url in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am sending request validation link to email.

ex :http://www.index.html?key=11111

In controller of www.index.html page I am writing init() method that is called on loading in index.html. In init() function I need to read 'key' data ie 11111 . How can I achieve this .
Please response as soon as possible

Comment: This might help:
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063673/whats-the-most-concise-way-to-read-query-parameters-in-angularjs

Comment: url isn't formatted for angular routing so you either want to change format or parse `location.search`