# ng-submit not working for this plunk

Tags: angularjs, ng-submit

I am new to angular js and was building my first app to display users while hitting the github API.

here's the plunk I was working on : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/bJxijtHV4kBmJ3heMxA9?p=preview

```
<form name="searchUser" ng-submit="Search(userName)">
  <input type="search" placeholder="User to find" ng-model="userName"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Javascript code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {
var Search = function(userName) {
$http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + userName)
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.person = response.data;
  });
 };
});
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong. This is my first app. Excuse any silly mistakes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be like following.

```
$scope.Search = function(userName){
//rest of the code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you needs to bind the submit function to scope property, because plain functions, variables are not accessible with in the html

like

```
$scope.Search = function(userName) {
   $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + userName)
       .then(function(response) {
           $scope.person = response.data;
       });
    };
});
```

here is the [updated Punker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ov0BW6np3gmO0EJ8rF2C?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to learn how to write function in angularJS controllers. You are defining search as variable object not a function.

Try this -

```
$scope.search = function(userName) {
$http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + userName)
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.person = response.data;
  });
};
```

If you are new to angularJS learn from here......

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063673/whats-the-most-concise-way-to-read-query-parameters-in-angularjs](http://AngularJS)