# Clarification in using $location object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very new to Angular JS and am running into a slight snag. I'm sure this is probably easy to answer but my research so far has been unsuccessful.

I'm using Visual Studio as my IDE and have followed the tutorial [here](http://angularfirst.com/your-first-angular-project-in-visual-studio/) to start a project using AngularJS.

The initial output of the tutorial works great. What I'm trying to do now is add in support for reading a parameter from the url. Something like `index.html?target=bob`

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063673/whats-the-most-concise-way-to-read-query-parameters-in-angularjs) which shows the general methods for using $location to grab the paramters from the url and display the results on the page.

I am having issues applying this logic to my current structure. I assume it's something basic that I've missed so far so apologies if this question is too simplistic.

Here's my current code.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Main as vm">

    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.food" placeholder="Enter food" />

    <p>Sriracha sauce is great with {{vm.food}}!</p>

    Target: {{vm.test}}<br />

    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.module.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', [], function ($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });

})();
```

**main.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('Main', main($location));

    function main($location) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.food = 'pizza';
        vm.test = $location.search()['target']
    }

})();
```

The page renders as such:

[image: Output]

I am getting the following errors in the console which seem obvious but I'm at a loss as to what my next step should be.
[image: Error]

Clearly the issue lies in main not understanding $location. But why? What do?!

Thanks!

> **SOLVED**
>
> Both [Claise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41491666/1766561) and [squiroid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41491485/1766561) provided excellent answers to this below.
>   Since squiroid's solution is what I'm currently using I'll accept that answer but Claise's answer provides a bit more in depth information on this issue for future reference.
>
> I'd like to note also that the second error listed above was solved by
>   adding `<base href="/">` to the head section of index.html
>
> Thanks everyone!

Comment: I'm not really sure about that controller function implementation. You might want to pass the `$location` service with `[]` if you are applying any automated minification.

Comment: See the official guide examples how they are passing `$scope`: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: Your error is regarding Main being undefined. If you want to keep the code as you have it, I would try moving Main function declaration above the line of code where its called.

Comment: @Joshua please check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working plunker for you.

https://plnkr.co/edit/GUDPceYFLNldiqd94vZ1?p=preview

Some code needs to be changed in controller.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('Main', ['$location', main]);

    function main($location) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.food = 'pizza';
        vm.test = $location.search()['target']
    }

})();
```

There were two problems:

1. Problem with you code is that you have called the main method instead of passing it as callback function
2. You haven't passed the `$location` from controller to the callback method.

   `['$location', main]`

**EDIT:** Updated the plunker and give the appropriate answer.

Comment: Writing the detailed answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a derivative style of angular declarations here, which allows you to declare all the controllers in a single block, with all the functions following, rather than the traditional inline method.  This works, but you have made a few errors in your use of this form.

First, the `.controller('Main', main($location));` line is incorrect.  the function `.controller()` is accepting  the name of the function as an *argument*, it is not *calling* the function.  Therefore, the `()`, and the list of arguments is unnecessary.  `controller('Main', main);` is what is expected here.

Moving to your function declaration next, `function main($location) {...}` will work, ***as long as your code is not minified***.  As soon as you minify your code, angular will no longer be able to identify which dependency `$location` represents, and the code will break.

Again, you can refer to inline injections, where you use

```
.controller('Main',['$inject', main]);
```

but you also have an option to provide another separation of the dependencies from the declarations.

Angular provides an alternative method, `$inject`.  You can assign an array to the `$inject` property of your function, to provide the correct dependencies.  `main.$inject = ['$location'];`.

In summary, here is the corrected main.js file:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('Main', main);

function main($location) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.food = 'pizza';
    vm.test = $location.search()['target']
}

main.$inject = ['$location'];
})();
```

And a Plunker showing the changes:  http://plnkr.co/edit/j9FnhiFPjkSrY5muhb0J?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app', [])
     .config(function ($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
     }));
})();
```

Try placing the `locationProvider` under config in your *app.module.js* as above. Also in your *main.js*, if `'target'` is the key value of the parameter you can write `vm.test = $location.search('target');`

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('Main', function($location) {
       var vm = this;
       vm.food = 'pizza';
       vm.test = $location.search('target');
    })();
```

Comment: Do you mean the config part or the controller?

Comment: No, `.controller('Main', main($location));` will probably throw a syntax error. You should create a state and test if it will or not. Probably will :)