# Angular JS Get HTTP Request Parameter

Tags: angularjs

I'm migrating a JSP/Spring project to Angular JS 1.X. Currently I'm stuck in following situation, appreciate if anyone can help.
My application is redirecting to a 3rd party app and after submitting a form response is coming back to again my application. In spring I used to get the request parameter using following code. How can I get the request parameters in Angular JS?

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;
..
Enumeration paramsEnum = request.getParameterNames();
while (paramsEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
 String paramName = (String) paramsEnum.nextElement()
 ....
}
```

Comment: Note that AngularJS is [EOL](https://blog.angular.io/stable-angularjs-and-long-term-support-7e077635ee9c), this isn't a great time to be migrating *to* it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the most concise way to read query parameters in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063673/whats-the-most-concise-way-to-read-query-parameters-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question because with Java/Spring we access the params sent by angularJS.

Anyway, If you want to access a **Url parameters of the current view**  you can use the angularjs `$location` service:

```
$location.search()
```

For example taking the 'impersonate_token' from the url and adding it to some variable:

```
if($location.search().token){ 
    var token = $location.search().token; 
    url += "?impersonate_token=" +token; 
}
```

if you want to manage the **Url parameters send to the server side**, you can do with angularjs `$http` service like this:

```
    $http({
        url: your/url, 
        method: "GET",
        params: {
           param_1: $scope.some_data
           param_2: $scope.some_data2
        }
   });
```

Comment: Question is not about sending request to server side. From a 3rd party application, a request is coming to my angular js application via URL call and I need to read those request parameter.

Comment: OK, so I think its option #1 in the Answer - an example was added.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $http.get(url)
   .then(function(response) {
   $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
  });
```

Comment: Please explain why this answers the question. Dumping code doesn't help future users :)